# WsO2 ESB development thru Tooling Vs Management Console

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Why does the management console provide features to develop a service or customize a component of WSO2 ESB?

What's the purpose of one Vs other?

Doesn't the development stops after handover of CAR files/artifacts to DevOps team?

My understanding with Management Console is to deploy, manage(start-stop) & monitor ESB services/integration flows.

Is there an overlap on these two ? The documentation itself provides two ways to do the same thing. I mean why?

TIA,

--M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these features are available in Management console for users to try out easily. For example, when they want to see what are available feature etc, quickly.

When you're using ESB in real development, you should use toolings instead.

Comment: Thanks, understood. Is this the official statement of WSO2 ? I wish there's an official community of WSO2 , where the roadmap, vision straegies of WSO2 products are shared publicly to developer communities directly, instead of SO.